# Is BDD mainly used in integration test?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd, bdd

A common story

```
Story: User logging in
  As a user
  I want to login with my details
  So that I can get access to the site
```

Given such a broad coverage, it is useless if I **mock** the system components such as DB in order to perform the test, so can I say that people mainly use BDD in integration test?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's my terminology.

- **Scenario:** an example of the user using the system, with all relevant components in place rather than mocked out. May be automated and used as an acceptance test, but the conversations between business, testers and devs are the most important aspect of BDD. [Often created using the *Given / When / Then* template](http://code.google.com/p/wipflash/source/browse/Example.PetShop.Scenarios/PetRegistrationAndPurchase.cs), sometimes in tools which allow for natural language capture such as [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/) or [JBehave](http://jbehave.org/).
- **Integration test:** Crosses the boundary of two components, and usually used to check the integrity of integration of those components. For instance, may be used to send messages back and forth between the client and server layers of a web interface, or to check database bindings with Hibernate, etc.. Does not necessarily involve the full stack. A scenario could be considered a particular kind of integration test. BDD doesn't really apply for most non-scenario integration tests, though you could still conceivably use the Given / When / Then template.
- **Unit test:** An example of a consuming class using another class, usually with collaborators mocked out. May also be an example of how a consuming class delegates work to its collaborators. That's how we talk about it in BDD, anyway (you can do BDD at both levels). Can [also use the Given / When / Then syntax](http://code.google.com/p/wipflash/source/browse/WiPFlash.Behavior/Framework/WaiterBehaviour.cs).
- **Story:** A slice through a feature to allow us to get faster feedback. The behavior of a feature may be illustrated with several scenarios, and these can also be used to help slice up the feature. Often illustrated with the *As a... I want... So that...* template, or the *In order to... as a... I want...* template of [Feature Injection](http://lizkeogh.com/2010/02/02/theyre-not-user-stories/).
- **Feature:** Features represent the way in which users will use the capabilities we’re giving them. This is the stage in which we start defining the concrete implementation and UI. A feature may be a web page, part of a web page, a module in a windows UI, part of an app, etc.
- **Capability:** Something a user can achieve with the system, or which the system can achieve. Ie: A user can *book a trade*, the system is secure enough to *withstand hackers*. Phrasing scenarios at this level helps them be independent of the UI and keeps them in the language of the business.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you really define Feature in terms of component?

Comment: @seb-rose There's some point at which we need to start looking at UX / UI. I call the things we're talking about at that point "features". We're now talking about *how* to provide capabilities, but we haven't decided what we're going to do first to get quick feedback, so it's not really about defining it; it's a short-hand label to help get the right people in the room for the conversations that need to happen. I use the word "component" here to mean "element" or "part" of a system, and if a web page or widget is a component, then, yes, I do.

Comment: @seb-rose Here are three blog posts I use to talk about feature injection in more detail: http://lizkeogh.com/2012/06/01/bdd-in-the-large/ http://lizkeogh.com/2012/07/07/examples-in-the-large/ http://www.infoq.com/articles/pulling-power

Comment: Thanks, Liz. I prefer your definition of feature from your blog post "BDD in the large" - "features represent the way in which users will use the capabilities we’re giving them." This chimes well with my understanding of a "feature", and seems quite far from the concept of "component".

Comment: Thanks for the feedback; edited accordingly!

Answer (score 11):

Your example is a user story, which describes acceptance test. Acceptance tests could have end-to-end scope, but not necessarily. Core difference between acceptance and integration tests, is what they are focused on. Acceptance test is business-focused and could be written/read by non-technical person (customer). On the other hand we have development-focused integration tests, which simply verify that two or more components could work together.

Back to BDD. It could be used in acceptance testing (feature level) and unit testing (code level). There are even different tools for different levels of BDD:

- SpecFlow (acceptance testing)
- NSpec, NBehave (unit testing)

Answer (score 3):

Behaviour Driven Development is thinking about the behaviour of a product in a given scenario. It extends both Test Driven Development and Domain Driven Design. Also BDD is thinking beyond integration test. BDD is about maximizing the communication between the Users, Developers, Testers, Managers and Analysts.

Integration Testing is considered as a step of BDD. Integration testing can also exist out of the context of BDD. As integration testing can be used to cover high-level behaviour of your application without dropping into the unit testing.

Behaviour is about the interactions between components of the system and so the use of mocking is fundamental to advanced TDD. Expertise in TDD begins to dawn at the point where the developer realizes that TDD is about defining behaviour rather than testing.

A user story may have a broad scope, as it is always a priority of developing human friendly software. It combines the pragmatic approach of Extreme Programming with Enough Up Front Thinking based on Macro Level Analysis to enable Macro Level Planning.

Answer (score 2):

Integration Testing is what we are using BDD for mainly - UI tests with Selenium. Although actually we are not mocking anything with these tests as the BDD Scenarios are used to drive SpecFlow to in turn drive Selenium Webdriver to perform user-journeys such as logging in, clicking menu links, creating records.  In fact I'm trying my hardest to do everything through the UI where possible.

I have been working towards and with the Business Analysts to write their user stories in a BDD fashion (in fact it is now in our contract with clients) and it has been very refreshing and useful to find that during the writing of stories in a BDD fashion, we discover edge-cases  that might not otherwise have been thought when we extrapolate the requirements into atomic steps (Given, When, Then).  It truly is a win-win scenario for both the business and the developers' perspective when we have a more common language to express requirements.